# What does the following mean ` <TFunction extends Function>(target: TFunction) => TFunction | void`

Tags: typescript

I'm looking at `lib.d.ts` file and there is the following there:

```
declare type ClassDecorator = <TFunction extends Function>(target: TFunction) => TFunction | void;
```

I don't quite understand the syntax. Can anyone help?

What I understand is that new type `ClassDecorator` is declared. This type extends from the function. But what is this: `<TFunction extends Function>`? And why is arrow used there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's declaring a type for a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) function with the base form of

```
<T>(target: T) => T | void;
```

Example

```
type MyFuncType = <T>(target: T) => T | void;

var myFunc: MyFuncType = <T>(target: T) => {
    return target;
}

var stringOrVoidResult = myFunc<string>("test");
var numberOrVoidResult = myFunc<number>(123);
```

`TFunction extends Function` means that the type that you are declaring the generic function to be when you use it, has to be of the type `Function`, which all classes are.

Example

```
class Animal {
    Eat: () => void;
    Sleep: () => void;
}

type MyFuncType = <T extends Animal>(target: T) => T | void;

var myFunc: MyFuncType = <T>(target: T) => {
    return target;
}

var stringOrVoidResult = myFunc<string>("test"); // Error, string is not a subtype of Animal
var numberOrVoidResult = myFunc<number>(123); // Error, number is not a subtype of Animal

class Dog extends Animal {

}

var dogOrVoidResult = myFunc<Dog>(new Dog()); //Ok, Dog is Animal
```

In the above examples, you don't really have to specify the generic type of the function as the compiler could understand that from the input argument. Although that is not always the case.

```
var stringOrVoidResult = myFunc("test");
var numberOrVoidResult = myFunc(123);
var dogOrVoidResult = myFunc(new Dog());
```

Comment: thanks, can you elaborate a bit on `with the base form of`? maybe show an example of a function with such type

Comment: why is arrow used here `<T>(target: T) => T | void;`?

Comment: That is specifying the return type of the function. E.g. `var funcThatReturnsString: () => string = () => "hello world";`

Comment: thanks, so `TypeScript` allows creating different types of functions, that return a value of specif type? How do I declare a type of function that always returns a value of type "string"?

Comment: and what's `(target:T)` in `<T>(target: T) => T | void;`?

Comment: @Maximus Yes. You could do that like `type stringFunc = () => string;` and then use it like `var helloWorldFunc: stringFunc = () => "Hello world";`

Comment: @Maximus `(target:T)` says that the function should take one argument and that the type of that argument should be the generic type `T`.

Comment: thanks, we're almost there :) what is `<T>` in the `<T>(target: T) => T | void;`?

Comment: @Maximus That is the syntax for specifying that the function is generic, and `T` is a placeholder for the actual type that you define it to be when you use the generic function. It does not have to be named `T` although that is the standard, you can name it whatever you want. You can also specify more than one type like `<T, U, Z>`

Comment: thanks, can you take a look [at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40716654/class-decorator-type-mismatch-error) question please?

Comment: _TFunction extends Function means that the type that you are declaring the generic function to be when you use it, has to be of the type Function, which all classes are._ - how would that be different if I used `<Function>(target: Function)...` instead of `<TFunction extends Function>(target: TFunction)`?

Comment: @Maximus I'm sorry, I missed your comment. `<Function>(target: Function)` is the same as `<T>(target: T)`, and the difference from `<TFunction extends Function>(target: TFunction)` is that the generic type (T in the first and TFunction in the second) has to be a `Function`in the second example, but can be any type in the first.