# Class decorator type mismatch error

Tags: typescript

The `ClassDecorator` is defined as:

```
declare type ClassDecorator = <TFunction extends Function>(target: TFunction) => TFunction | void;
```

I've written it like that:

```
export function ClassDecorator(params: any): ClassDecorator {
    return function (target) {
        Object.seal(target);
        Object.seal(target.prototype);
    }
}
```

But the compiler gives me an error:

```
Error:(2, 12) TS2322:Type '(target: any, key: any, descriptor: any) => void' is not assignable to type 'ClassDecorator'.
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `ClassDecorator` is defined to be a function that takes one argument, you return a function that takes three arguments, that is not compatible and that is why you get the error message.

Comment: thanks, once I fix that I get another error: `Error:(4, 22) TS2339:Property 'prototype' does not exist on type 'Object'.`

Comment: @it should work if you say that target is `any`, which it looks like you do implicitly in your code. Do you say that it should be of the type `Object`?

Comment: it should be of the type `Function`, or `TFunction` as I understand from the type definition

Comment: @Maximus Yes, but you can get around that by using the type `any`.

Comment: You could also do something like `type ClassType = { (): void; prototype: any; }` and `function (target:ClassType)`

Comment: well, when I put like this `(target: Function) {` It's weird because `noImplicitAny` is false by default. Any ideas? And I still don't understand what's the difference between `TFunction` and `Function`

Comment: @Maximus `TFunction` is the generic type for that function, `Function` is the type of a function. `<T extends Function> ` means the same thing. And it's just like `<T extends MyClass>` or something like that. It's for defining specific types that you can use in a generic function/class, instead of all types.